# Script monitoring

Tags: shell

I have this script that monitors another script if it crashes it automatically starts it.

```
while { myscript;}; do
    echo "'myscript' crashed. Restarting..." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

But sometimes the script will hang even though the script is not working it will still run but myscript prints something when this happens. It prints "script dead" so when it prints this I want to kill the script and restarts. How Can I do this, please.

Comment: What does it mean, that the script "hangs"? How can you know whether `myscript` is still doing something useful or not? If you know for sure that `myscript`should not take longer than a certain time, you could wrap its invocation with a `timeout` command. On Linux see _man timeout_.

Comment: with this while-loop:
- If 'myscript' has finished successfully, it starts again after 1sec pause.
- If unsuccessfully, then this while-loop ends.
Do you mean this logic under monitor?

Comment: if your goal to start 'myscript' again unconditionally after its finish, that would be something like `while true; do myscript; sleep 1; done`

Comment: Why don't you make _the script_ exit when it _prints "script dead"_?

Comment: I don't really know how to do that @Armali I'm beginner sorry if my question is dumb

Comment: It's done by putting `; exit` after _"script dead"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can don with `pgrep` function which can check the running process.

So here I added while true logic so that once process not found in running state at that time else condition will work and process will restart.

```
while true; do
    if pgrep -f myscript >/dev/null; then
        echo "'myscript' is running well..."
        sleep 1
    else
        echo "'myscript' is not running so restarting..." >&2
        # Kill the previous instance
        pkill -f -x myscript
        sleep 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: It keeps printing 'myscript' is not running so restarting...

Comment: You need to double check the command path of kill and restart is correct. Also you need to check the time taken for process stop and start. If it will take more time then you need to adjust sleep duration based on processor time.